# how to use element attribute value to show / hide div in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I want to show div based the value of div's attribute values.

```
<div ng-show="" data-views="{{viewstate}}" id="Question_ID_{{questionid}}"  >aaa</div>
```

i want to do something like below

```
 <div ng-show="data-views" data-views="{{viewstate}}" id="Question_ID_{{questionid}}" >
```

how to pass data-views attribute value to ng-show=""

Is this possible

Comment: just use same expresion without {{ }} in the ng-show. ng-show="viewstate"

Answer (score 0):

better way to show hide is take a scope variable in controller and use it like below if your value is boolean otherwise use conditions in ng-show.

$scope.viewstate =true/false;

```
<div ng-show="viewstate" data-views="{{viewstate}}" id="Question_ID_{{questionid}}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses truthy/falsy values which means that the expression

```
if (viewstate)
```

will return true if the object exists and false if it is null or undefined. Knowing this, you can use it directly in your ng-show. Just don't use {{}} around it or it will be interpreted as an expression instead.

```
ng-show=viewstate
```